# Preview image in image control with fileupload control with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

In my asp.net application, for a particular set of users, I have to make the application run in IE8. In the page I have fileupload html control and image control. And below code i have written for preview the image,

```
               $("#browsePhoto").change(function () {
                    var input = this;
                    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

                        var reader = new FileReader();

                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            var fileSize = Math.round(e.total / 1024);
                            if (fileSize < 100) {
                                $("[id$=img_userPhotoPreview]").attr('src', e.target.result);
                                $("[id$=hdnSrc]").val(e.target.result);
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("Image size is greater than 100kb. Please choose an image of size less than 100kb.");
                                $("[id$=img_userPhotoPreview]").attr('src', "");
                                $("#browsePhoto").val("");
                            }
                        }
                        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                    }
                });
```

The above code works fine in IE10 and above and all other browser. But fails in IE8.

Comment: [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) is not supported in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not support files property of input so you can use in place of input.files to e.target.value , And FileReader() function is not defiend for IE8 and IE9 so you can not use file reader for reading its size and drawing image.

So if u want use the same code my suggestion is don't run this in IE8 or IE9, now a days no one is using this.

Otherwise I am modifiing ur code for IE8 :

```
         <html >
        <head runat="server">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#browsePhoto").change(function (e) {
                    debugger;
                    var input = this;
                    if (e.target.value) {
                        $("[id$=img_userPhotoPreview]").attr('src', e.target.value);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
            <input type="file" id="browsePhoto" name="browsePhoto" onclick="" />
            <img id="img_userPhotoPreview" src="" height="200" width="200">
            </div>
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

But here u can't get the exact size of image.So best is : for checking size u can use image height and width property.